# resource for practice html and css?

Tags: html, css

Is there some page with a challenge or something to practice? Because, I do not know what to practice now. A place similar to Codecademy, but not for learning, only because I already know HTML and CSS, just challenges like PSD to code for example. I tried to get on fiverr and too earn money but the first one is difficult :(

Comment: simply come here to this site and try to help people having trouble and you will practise by trying to solve their issue

Answer (score -1):

You should checkout Codepen.  Even though it is very late you could still participate in #codevember which is a very popular even that has revolved a bit around it.

Here is the link:
http://www.codepen.io

Just as an extra bonus CodePen is **FREE**!

Here are some examples of what the interface and website look like.

[image: CodePen Example]

Comment: ty but u have ti pay for practice ? .-.